# Archive a document library after 30 days?

Tags: 2010, document-library, records-management, records-center

I am very new to this concept of archiving and record management.

I have the following requirements:

1. Create a document library when a new event is added. I can do this with an event receiver.
2. The document library should be archived for 30 days.

The 2nd item I have no idea how to do it using code.  Where is it archived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to archive would be to export the document library using the [Export-SPWeb PowerShell command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx#section1). Use [Import-SPWeb](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx) for restoration (archives are file packages that can use optional compression. See the -Path and other options in the Export-SPWeb command).

Other PowerShell posts to manage the document library (cleanups, uploads, etc) -

- [Using PowerShell to clean up SharePoint document library files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulking/archive/2011/10/14/using-powershell-to-clean-up-sharepoint-document-library-files-with-no-versions.aspx)
- [Use PowerShell Cmdlets to Manage SharePoint Document Libraries](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/23/use-powershell-cmdlets-to-manage-sharepoint-document-libraries.aspx)
- [Phil Childs' Get-SPScripts on Document Management](http://get-spscripts.com/search/label/Document%20Management?updated-max=2010-10-12T09:15:00%2b01:00&max-results=20&start=9&by-date=false)

If you must - there are commercial companies like AvePoint, Metalogix, Idera & Axceler that provide utilities for library archving & backup administration.